# sublime text 3 quick panel multiple selection

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, multipleselection

I am writing a plugin for Sublime Text 3. It allows the user to generate getter/setter/operator in C++ language

I am using quick panel to ask to the user which attribute will be used by the generator

```
def generate(self, itemSelected):
    print("generating", itemSelected)

def run():
    ### Some code
    attributes = classCpp.getAllAttributeName();
    window.show_quick_panel(attributes, self.generate)
```

The problem is I can't have severals items selected. How can I do that ?

For the getter/setter that is not a big problem: I can call the command again. But i need to select many item for generate the operator.

I found this [documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.WindowCommand). but I never found how to get multiple items selected with a quick panel.

If that's no possible, where I can post a "issue" to ask to develop this functionality

Sorry for my English, I am learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to use [`window.show_input_panel()`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window) to allow the user to enter the attributes they'd like to use. Unfortunately, it isn't currently possible to select multiple items in a quick panel, and honestly I don't see that type of functionality being implemented anytime soon, unless an entirely new class of panel is invented.

If you would like to file an enhancement request, you can do so [here](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core). Please make sure to read all the `.md` documents before posting. This site is run by the community, and while we have some feedback that Jon Skinner (Sublime's author) does know about it and has taken some of the suggestions/bug reports into account in the past, obviously there is no guarantee that he'll do anything about this particular issue. Good luck, though!